# Get-Help : Cannot find the type for custom attribute 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell module that I have written, it contains two functions that use [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] as a parameter type:

This is the parameter list for the first function:

```
param(
     [parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]      $a
    ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]      $b
    ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]      $c
    ,[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $d
)
```

and this is the parameter list for the second function:

```
param(
      [parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]      $a                                          
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]      $b                              
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string[]]    $c                                 
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$true)]  [string]      $d       
     ,[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $e
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]      $f                              
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]      $g                              
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]      $h                              
     ,[parameter(mandatory=$false)] [switch]      $i                              
)
```

Both functions execute as expected, however, when I perform a Get-Help on the 2 nd function I get:

Get-Help : Cannot find the type for custom attribute 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'. Make sure that the
assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Help Invoke-PfaDbRefresh
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ([System.Managem...ndatory=$true)]:AttributeAst) [Get-Help], RuntimeEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CustomAttributeTypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

despite the fact that Get-Help works perfectly fine on the first function.

Any ideas ?

Comment: There are two things wrong in the parameter list for function two. 1) the very first parameter does not have a variable attached to it. 2) the 7th parameter `$e` is not unique. Other than that, i cannot reproduce the error message you show..

Comment: Theo - the observations you have pointed down are due to the fact I have incorrectly transcribed the code into the question, for the second example, the code I am using does have both unique parameters and a parameter name for each parameter type, I've corrected the code to reflect this, but thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ChrisAdkin did you perhaps put an extra pair of `()` in the `PSCredential` type constraint? The only way I can reproduce this is by doing that, ie. `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential()]` - which makes sense, because the parser will assume it's an attribute decorator and not a type literal

Answer (score 0):

I've applied all the latest updates to my windows 2016 server, rebooted it and all now appears to work. This does not explain why Get-Help was working for one function using PSCredential but not the other. But I'm happy this is resolved.